# Add values to the file from excel sheet with pyhon

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm  novice in python and trying to create a file by adding data from second column of an excel file

excel sheet looks like the one below,

```
DC_CODE     APP_NAME    HOST_NAME
APAC        Tomcat      host1.example.com
APAC        Nginx       host1.example.com
APAC        Apache      host1.example.com
```

I'm using this piece of code to print the values,

```
import xlrd 
import os.path

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('/home/akbharat/Documents/OCIC/deploy_fed_ocic','podhosts_test_file.xlsx'))
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 
for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 2))
```

How can we print the output to a file with the heading HOST_NAME removed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `pandas` library for that, the following code might work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join('/home/akbharat/Documents/OCIC/deploy_fed_ocic','podhosts_test_file.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('PythonExport.xlsx')
df[['DC_CODE', 'APP_NAME']].to_excel(writer,'Sheet5')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I'm looking to have the column HOST_NAME in a text file removing the row HOST_NAME: something like ` HOST_NAME
host1.example.com
host2.example.com
 host3.example.com`